# while runnig playbook for reboot why "remote side unexpectedly closed network connection" coming while rebooting the firewall in host file

Tags: ansible

The following playbook I used to reboot the firewall server which is in host file. using ansible-2.4.0 version

```
---
 - name: reboot
   hosts: xx.xxx.xx.xxx

   tasks:
     - name: reboot
       shell: shutdown -r now && sleep 5
       async: 45
       poll: 0
     - pause:
         seconds=120

     - local_action: shell ansible -m ping xx.xxx.xx.xxx
       register: result
       until: result.rc==0
       retries: 30
       delay: 10

     - shell: uptime
```

I am trying to reboot the firewall server and after reboot it will automatically up, but while running this playbook I am getting the "remote side unexpectedly closed network connection" its not rebooting the firewall. anyone help me.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please edit your question and format the code and error message correctly in code blocks. You have a formatting guide on the editor page. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is an ansible module to perform reboot, please look in it.

```
- name: Unconditionally reboot the machine with all defaults
  reboot:
```

Link https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/reboot_module.html

After your reboot task, add the below task

```
- name: Wait for the reboot to complete 
  wait_for_connection:
    connect_timeout: 20
    sleep: 5
    delay: 5
    timeout: 300
```

Comment: but I am using the ansible version-2.4 but that module is in ansible version-2.7, as well as I am unable to update to the version-2.7.

Comment: try  shell: sleep 5 && shutdown -r now or shell: sleep 5 && reboot

Comment: by using these commands also it shows that the same problem putty fattal error "remote side unexpectedly closed the network connection"

Comment: is it during the reboot task execution or before that itself? Please paste the entire output in your question

Comment: I am installed the ansible-2.7.0 and by using the reboot module it shows the error as " FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 0, "msg": "Running reboot with local connection would reboot the control node.", "rebooted": false}
"

Comment: you are not rebooting the remote node? Are you rebooting the ansible server itself? the error shows so

Comment: during the reboot task that error is comming as soon as "the sleep 5 && shutdown -r now or shell: sleep 5 && reboot " execution

Comment: yes It looks like that its not rebooting the remote node , it rebooting the ansible server itself. what to do now? help me

Comment: as well as I tried the reboot module in another playbook it shows the  " FAILED! => {"changed": false, "elapsed": 0, "msg": "Running reboot with local connection would reboot the control node.", "rebooted": false} "  error.

Comment: what you have given here? hosts: xx.xxx.xx.xxx you should give your remote node name. remove the line '- local_action: shell ansible -m ping xx.xxx.xx.xxx' and add the updated one from the answer

Comment: that xx.xxx.xx.xxx is the host server which i have given in the host file